# Regression with TBATS error?

Tags: regression, time-series, arima, multiple-seasonalities, tbats

I'm working on a time series model which includes multiple seasonal components (daily and weekly). I believe the best way to approach this would be BATS/TBATS model, however I have a concern if I can incorporate external factors in a proper way. I'm thinking about a regression with BATS/TBATS error, in analogy to a regression with ARIMA error:

1. Fit a linear regression to forecast the outcome based on available
   external predictors
2. Fit BATS/TBATS model to forecast residuals;

Do you see any fundamental problems with this approach and is there a better way to build a model with multiple seasonal components and external predictors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linear regression will be inefficient at best, and possibly inconsistent if the errors are non-stationary. A better approach is to add in multiple seasonal components as Fourier terms in the regression with ARIMA errors. An example with a single seasonal period is given at http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecasting-weekly-data/. That can be extended to multiple seasonal terms by adding Fourier terms with different periods.